# Use flask variable outside of context

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

In the Flask application (initialized in `__init__.py`) I have two blueprints - `auth` and `main` . In the `auth` blueprint I'm trying to set some variable (will be loaded from db and depends from `current_user.get_id()`) which should be used in `main` blueprint as url-prefix:

auth.py

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user_inst = user.query.filter_by(username=username).first()


    if not user_inst or not check_password_hash(user_inst.password, password):
        flash('Invalid credentials. Check you input and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login')) 

    login_user(user_inst)
    
    g.team_name = 'some_team_name'
    #session['team_name'] = 'some_team_name'
    
    # if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
    return redirect(url_for('main.some_func'))
```

In the main blueprint, it's required to get the `team_name` variable:

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, static_folder="static", static_url_path="", url_prefix=g.team_name)
```

Could you please advise is there a proper way to import variable from `auth` to `main` (before its initializing) without getting:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic fix of your problem is registering blueprints within `app.app_context():`

And seems like it is your first flask project and it is a common problem with thinking about the project structure. Read about Flask application factory pattern and apply it.

`your_app/__init__.py`

```
def create_app(app_config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        from your_app.somewhere import team_name

        app.register_blueprint(team_name)
    return app
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: another tip: search in github open repositories for `flask create_app` and simply copy a project design))